# Getting PyCall to work with Julia and Enthought's Canopy

Tags: python, enthought, canopy, julia

There's some weirdness with Enthought's Canopy and Julia with the implementation of `PyCall` (I guess this has to do with Canopy not updating `distutils.sysconfig` ??).

There is [some discussion](https://github.com/stevengj/PyCall.jl/issues/37) on this that fixes the problem by pointing `PyCall` to the correct shared library.

**How do I make this permanent** (How do I change `distutils.sysconfig`)?

Some output:

```jl
julia> using PyPlot
ERROR: could not load module python: dlopen(python.dylib, 9): image not found
 in pyinitialize at /Users/bdhammel/.julia/PyCall/src/PyCall.jl:422
 in pyimport at /Users/bdhammel/.julia/PyCall/src/PyCall.jl:105
 in include at boot.jl:238
 in include_from_node1 at loading.jl:114
 in reload_path at loading.jl:140
 in _require at loading.jl:58
 in require at loading.jl:43
at /Users/bdhammel/.julia/PyPlot/src/PyPlot.jl:32

julia> using PyCall

julia> pyinitialize("/Users/bdhammel/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/System/lib/libpython2.7.dylib")
/Users/bdhammel/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/System/lib/libpython2.7.dylib: /Users/bdhammel/Library/Enthought/Canopy_64bit/System/lib/libpython2.7.dylib: cannot execute binary file

julia> using PyPlot
Warning: Possible conflict in library symbol dtrtri_
Warning: Possible conflict in library symbol dgetri_
Warning: Possible conflict in library symbol dgetrf_

julia> plot([1,2])
1-element Array{Any,1}:
 PyObject <matplotlib.lines.Line2D object at 0x115b95090>
```

and it plots the line

I'd like to set this up to work, without having to do the `pyinitialize` bit.

**From the linked discussion:**
PyCall runs the python executable and executes:

```py
import distutils.sysconfig
print(distutils.sysconfig.get_config_var('LDLIBRARY'))
print(distutils.sysconfig.get_config_var('PYTHONFRAMEWORKPREFIX'))
```

**Where are these Paths stored, and what should I change?**

Output in python for those commands:

```py
In [1]: import distutils

In [2]: print(distutils.sysconfig.get_config_var('LDLIBRARY'))
Python.framework/Versions/2.0.0.dev-f1c6cfc/Python

In [3]: print(distutils.sysconfig.get_config_var('PYTHONFRAMEWORKPREFIX'))
/Library/Frameworks

In [4]: distutils.__file__
Out[4]: '/Applications/Canopy.app/appdata/canopy-1.0.3.1262.macosx-x86_64/Canopy.app/Contents/lib/python2.7/distutils/__init__.pyc'
```

Lastly: **Do I need to be worried about the `cannot execute binary file` or `Possible conflict ...` parts?**

Answer (score 1):

See [PyCall issue #42](https://github.com/stevengj/PyCall.jl/issues/42), which is the right place for this discussion.  Matters have improved somewhat, but there are still some runtime path issues on Windows with Canopy/EPD, and for now I would recommend using Anaconda Python instead.